# PHP fails to load imagick extension (Windows)

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I have had zero issues with this in years. Prior to that, we were always having trouble getting php_imagick.dll to load. Suddenly, this process is failing on 2 machines (maybe more, but we know of 2 for sure, both dev machines). Nothing has changed - no updates, no config, nothing, just suddenly, on 2 dev machines it fails. This does not fail on at least 1 other dev machine and our test machine (luckily also not failing in production).

C:\windows\system32>C:\PHP\php.exe -cC:/php/devrc/php.ini -m

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'imagick' (tried: ext\imagick (The specified module could not be found.), ext\php_imagick.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0

I have tried everything I can think, and as far as I can tell, these are identical.

I even took a brand new VM. Copied the files from the failing machine (c:\PHP and c:\imagemagick) to that machine. Installed vcredist140. Failed with the same issue. Added c:\imagemagick to the %PATH% variable. Works!

I have verified that c:\imagemagick is in the path and even tried copying the files to c:\PHP, still fails. Something has changed that is affecting 2, and only 2 (so far), machines. All machines are Windows 10 21H1 or Server 2019, the 2 that are failing are Windows 10 21H1.

We are using the 7.4.21 build by Jan E on https://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?t=6359, including the artifact created for the c:\imagemagick folder. However, I tried https://mlocati.github.io/articles/php-windows-imagick.html as well.

I know they are identical as we put both c:\PHP and c:\imagemagick in a Git repo.

Comment: Now this makes no sense. Suddenly, both machines that were failing to load the extension are not anymore, but now all of our dev machines (thankfully this has not hit test or prod), are failing like this:

RegistryKeyLookupFailed `CoderModulesPath' @ error/module.c/GetMagickModulePath/665

Comment: Now, I switched to this version of Image Magick and php_imagick.dll, https://mlocati.github.io/articles/php-windows-imagick.html, and now it's all working. Still don't know what I did to fix the original problem.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use deplister.exe (contained in all binary zips from windows.php.net) to track the dependecies. So call `deplister php_imagick.dll`; this should list all dependencies, and whether they can be found.

Comment: I don't see a way to format this result in the comment, but all deps are OK. C:\PHP>deplister.exe ext\php_imagick.dll
php7.dll,OK
CORE_RL_MagickWand_.dll,OK
CORE_RL_MagickCore_.dll,OK
KERNEL32.dll,OK
VCRUNTIME140.dll,OK
api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll,OK
api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll,OK
api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll,OK
api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll,OK
api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll,OK
api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll,OK
api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll,OK